# default text in textbox wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, checkbox, default

I have a `TextBox`, its `Text` property is bound to a property of type `double` named `Grade`. I also have a `CheckBox`, when the `CheckBox` is checked I want the `Grade` to take an auto calculated value (i.e. automatically set to MaxScore/Count of questions). If the `CheckBox` is not checked then I want to set and change the `Grade` Manually. My question is **how can I implement this?**

```
<TextBox Height="23"
   Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible2, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   Text="{Binding Path=Grade,UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,453,0,0"
   Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

and i bind this to:

```
 public double Grade
        {
            get
            {

                return grade;
            }
            set
            {
                grade = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Grade");

                foreach (ExaminationQuestion exaq in
                         this.Examination.ExaminationQuestions)
                {
                    if (exaq.Question.Guid == SelectedQuestionDropList.Guid)
                    {
                        exaq.Grade = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your VM, have another public Property Auto and make sure your Checkbox binds to it and so does your TextBox (so that it becomes readonly/disabled/hidden). And my default AutoCheck will be true

Answer (score 0):

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="Grade" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Width="120"
                 Text="{Binding Path=GradeDisplay}"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding EnableBox}"
                  />
        <Label Content="Auto?" />
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAuto}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

And for the View Model

```
public bool EnableBox { get; set; }
    public string GradeDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            if (EnableBox)
                return Grade.ToString();
            else
                return "AUTO";
        }
        set
        {
            double result;
            if (double.TryParse(value, out result))
                Grade = result;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GradeDisplay");
        }
    }


    private bool _IsAuto;        
    public bool IsAuto
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsAuto;
        }

        set
        {
            _IsAuto = value;
            EnableBox = !value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GradeDisplay");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EnableBox");
        }
    }

    private double _Grade;
    private double Grade
    {
        set
        {
            _Grade = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (IsAuto)
            {
                // CODE TO GET AUTO GRADE
                return 0.0; 
            }
            else
            {  // RETURN MANUALLY SET GRADE
                return _Grade; 
            }
        }

    }

    // CTOR
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        IsAuto = false;
    }
```

Comment: But if it is set to auto, i still have to be able to change this value. So in my example, i have 4 questions, with a maximum score on 20. I fill this in , the system gives default in the textboxes Auto, so each question on 5 points. But then , if i decide i want to change 1 question to 8 points. So i change the textbox with "auto" in it in 8, so the other questions come each on 3 points. I have a listview and if i select one i can change the details ( here the grade).

Comment: Yeah, that is different all together, I would restate your question because it reads nothing like this comment.